# Regex for getting content between $ chars from a text

Tags: python, regex

The problem:
I need to extract strings that are between `$` characters from a block of text, but i'm a total n00b when it comes to regular expressions.

For instance from this text:
`Li Europan lingues $es membres$ del sam familie. Lor $separat existentie es un$ myth.`

i would like to get an array consisting of:
`{'es membres', 'separat existentie es un'}`

A little snippet in Python would be great.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Import the **[`re`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html)** module, and use `findall()`:

```
>>> import re
>>> p = re.compile('\$(.*?)\$')
>>> s = "apple $banana$ coconut $delicious ethereal$ funkytown"
>>> p.findall(s)
['banana', 'delicious ethereal']
```

The pattern `p` represents a dollar sign (`\$`), then a non-greedy match group (`(...?)`) which matches characters (`.`) of which there must be zero or more (`*`), followed by another dollar sign (`\$`).

Answer (score 3):

You can use re.findall:

```
>>> re.findall(r'\$(.*?)\$', s)
['es membres', 'separat existentie es un']
```

Comment: @Michael, some might think an answer like this deserves a link to the docs (I do), but it's succinct and correct so it certainly doesn't deserve a downvote for the lack.  I'll counteract it with an upvote.

Answer (score 1):

The regex below captures everything between the $ characters non-greedily

\$(.*?)\$

Answer (score 1):

```
import re;
m = re.findall('\$([^$]*)\$','Li Europan lingues $es membres$ del sam familie. Lor $separat existentie es un$ myth');
```

Comment: You don’t need to escape the `$` inside a character class.

Comment: Although the OP didn't say his input could include empty pairs of dollar signs (no characters between), the use of "+" instead of "*" means this would get out of sync if that did occur.  More importantly, without a group (using parantheses), the output includes the dollar signs.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative without regexes which works for this simple case:

```
>>> s="Li Europan lingues $es membres$ del sam familie. Lor $separat existentie es un$"
>>> s.split("$")[1::2]
['es membres', 'separat existentie es un']
```

Just split the string on '$' (this gives you a python list) and then only use every 'second' element of this list.

Comment: -1 It DOESN'T work. Did you compare your answer with what the OP expected? Hint: try it again with [1::2] instead of [::2]

Comment: True (must have typed/answered too fast). Edited accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

Valid regex demo in Perl:

```
my $a = 'Li Europan lingues $es membres$ del sam familie. Lor $separat existentie es un$ myth.';
my @res;
while ($a =~ /\$([^\$]+)\$/gos)
{
 push(@res, $1);
}

foreach my $item (@res)
{
 print "item: $item\n";
}
```

flags: s - treat all input text as single line, g - global

Comment: The question was tagged "Python" and included an explicit request for a Python snippet in the answer.

Comment: Well, it was a "would-be-great" type of request. I don't think the lack of python snippet justifies downvote. Naturally, I wouldn't upvote it either.